# How to execute the contents of H2's RunScript command programatically?

Tags: java, jpa, h2

I am executing the following RunScript on a H2 database in my Java code:

```
RunScript.execute("jdbc:h2:mem:testDB", "SA", "","truncate-all-database-tables.sql",Charsets.UTF_8, false);
```

Where the contents of truncate-all-database-tables.sql is:

```
SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE;
TRUNCATE TABLE USER;
TRUNCATE TABLE TEAM;
TRUNCATE TABLE TEAM_USER;
SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY TRUE;
```

I was wondering how to do this solely in code, rather than having to use RunScript and a separate .sql file? E.g. using javax.persistence.Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Queries is the way to go. See the documentation of [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

E.g

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE");
query.executeUpdate();
query = em.createNativeQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE USER");
query.executeUpdate();
.......
```